# How to list all items in the MongoDB on the tree structure?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, graphlookup

Consider the structure like this:

[image]

```
class Group {
  _id: ObjectId
  subGroups: ObjectId[]
  name: string
  info: string
}
```

A document for Group A in the database should be...

```
_id: ObjectId("6092387f9c69970c20fe648a")
subGroups: [
  ObjectId("6092387f9c69970c20fe648b"),  // Group B
  ObjectId("6092387f9c69970c20fe648c"), // Group C
],
name: "Group A",
info: "..."
```

How can I query in the mongodb to get all children including itself?

For example,

Query for A: Output A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J

Query for B: Output D, E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is called [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/), it recursively iterates until no more matches are found, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "name": "Group A"
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$subGroups",
      connectFromField: "subGroups",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "groupHierarchy",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            "$name"
          ],
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$groupHierarchy",
              as: "group",
              in: "$$group.name"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3DcLPysSJMv)

Comment: Is it possible to get the list of groups (the whole document) instead of  only name?

Comment: Yea, in the final projection stage you can see i return just the names as that was your requested output, you can just delete it and get the full documents.

Comment: If I remove the project stage, I found the Group A will be missing in the groupHierarchy. How can I add it to the final result?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-twcVhPwT9a for example, you decide the structure you want and use some structure manipulation to achieve it.